# Lock the parent jframe when child frame open

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want lock the parent frame when child frame opened. I tried creating a parent object in child and set that enabled(false) but it didn't work the way I wanted. How to do that in java?

Comment: Lock means do you want to hide parentFrame and open childFrame ?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want a modal dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a modal dialog is not enough you can use the glasspane of the first JFrame and make it consume all mouse and keyboard events. But for 99.9% of all cases this is just reinventing what a modal dialog does for free.

Comment: modal dialog is what i wanted... ty

Answer (score 3):

This depends, but the basic process would be to use modal dialog of some kind, depending on your needs.  This will prevent the parent window from being accessed by the user while the child window is open...

Take a look at [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details...